# Redirect http to https and www to non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I am trying to redirect my site and I seem to run into an issue each time I try to get it to redirect to https://example.com from www.example.com.

If I type example.com in the browser it redirects me fine to https://example.com.  I get the following message whenever I type www.example.com instead of just example.com.

**This site can’t provide a secure connection
www.example.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
HIDE DETAILS
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.**

I have tried many different rewrite conditions in my htaccess file but none seem to work.

This is what I currently have as of my last test...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all connection to SSL/443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

If anyone could help in getting the redirect from the www version to the non-www version using https it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check what server that hostname actually points to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid SSL certificate and can you go to https://example.com without an error?

Otherwise change the last line to:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

Comment: I have a certificate for the domain without the www and I can go to https version without an issue.  I tried what you said and still get the same error.